# define the origin of rotation from groups of points.

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, numerical-methods

So I have a group of points $K = [X_{1},X_{2},...,X_{n}]$ in $R^{3}$ that have been rotated by some unknown angles around an unknown point $p$ giving a new list of points $K' = [X'_{1},X'_{2},...,X'_{n}]$ where p is some fixed point and $X_{i}$ is a column vector $\left< x_{i},y_{i},z_{i}\right>^{T}$

From what I remember in geometry class, the chord of a sphere created by two points on the surface say in this case $\overline{X_{1}X'_{1}}$ has a perpendicular bisector plane that passes through the center of the sphere or in this case the point $p$ is the center of all of the spheres.

I know that all of the points $K$ have been rotated around the same point $p$ with the same rotation angles to give $K'$.  I can construct the equation of the perpendicular bisector plane:

$$(x_{i}-x'_i)x+(y_{i}-y'_{i})y+(z_{i}-z'_{i})z = D$$

Where the right hand side is the function evaluated at the midpoint of the line segment $\overline{X_{i}X'_{i}}$ to get the offset:

$$D=\frac{1}{2}(x_{i}-x'_{i})(x_{i}+x'_{i})+\frac{1}{2}(y_{i}-y'_{i})(y_{i}+y'_{i})+\frac{1}{2}(z_{i}-z'_{i})(z_{i}+z'_{i})$$

$$D = \frac{(x_{i}^2-{x'}_{i}^2)+(y_{i}^2-{y'}_{i}^2)+(z_{i}^2-{z'}_{i}^2)}{2}$$

Since the perpindicular bisector of all of the line segments formed by pairs of $K$ and $K'$ should pass through the $p$, I'm hoping to find a least squares solution in the form $Ap=b$ for the origin.

$$A = \left[\begin{array}{ccc} (x_{1}-{x'}_1)&(y_{1}-{y'}_{1})&(z_{1}-{z'}_{1})\\
  (x_{2}-x'_2)&(y_{2}-y'_{2})&(z_{2}-z'_{2})\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots\\
(x_{n}-x'_n)&(y_{n}-y'_{n})&(z_{n}-z'_{n})    \end{array}    \right]$$

Then the b construction.

$$b =\frac{1}{2} *\left[\begin{array}{ccc} (x_{1}^2-{x'}_{1}^2) + (y_{1}^2-{y'}_{1}^2)+(z_{1}^2-{z'}_{1}^2) \\
(x_{2}^2-{x'}_{2}^2) + (y_{2}^2-{y'}_{2}^2)+(z_{2}^2-{z'}_{2}^2)\\
\vdots\\
(x_{n}^2-{x'}_{n}^2) +(y_{n}^2-{y'}_{n}^2)+(z_{n}^2-{z'}_{n}^2)
  \end{array}    \right]$$

And finally "I should be able to solve this using the normal equation":

$$p=(A^{T}*A)^{-1}*(A^{T}*b)$$

**But alas it doesn't work.  I have tried it by generating random points then rotating them around a predetermined point $p_0$ to see if the $p$ I get back is the same point and it doesn't work.  Any ideas?**

Comment: What exactly do you mean that all of the points have been rotated by "some unknown angles around an unknown origin"?  A rotation in $\mathbb{R}^3$ doesn't have an origin -- it has an _axis_, i.e. a line of fixed points for the rotation.

Comment: @Jim Belk The points are measurements of a rigid body that has be rotated around a fixed point  $x$ in R3.  All I can do is take measurements after the rotation of the same points.  So essentially.  $R*(p-x) + x$ for the rotation.  Where $p$ is a point on the surface.

Comment: $p' = R*(p - x) + x$ rather

Comment: Any rotation that fixes a point $x$ will also fix an entire line through $x$, which means that there's not a unique choice of $x$.  There's no way to recover $x$ from the rotation data because $x$ isn't well-defined.

Comment: @JimBelk, That's a good point.  I have an overdetermined system of equations, I can probably afford to remove trivial solutions where $x = x'$.